# The meaning of "along" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw this in a video:

> [...] Drink a lot of water to speed the process *along*

What does "along" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

In “**speed the process along**,”

## “Speed” is a verb

The word “speed“ is most commonly a noun, but here is a verb meaning to increase the speed.

## “Along” shows progress toward the finish

Along, as in “along a journey“ is used to describe the progress of something from start to finish.

---

> along — Adverb:
>
> toward a direction or goal; forward:
>
> How far along are you with your homework?

---

> along — Preposition — (FROM ONE END TO ANOTHER)
>
> from one part of a road, river, etc. to another:
>
> - a romantic walk along the beach/river
> - We walked along the beach collecting small crabs in a bucket.
> - The room was so dark, I had to feel my way along the wall to the door.
> - Halfway along the wall he overbalanced and fell.
> - Cut along the dotted line.
>
> — [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/along)

Answer (score 0):

Drink a lot of water to speed the process along.

The word "along" in the sentence is an adverb. Usually, we use it  in the sense of on, forward, or onward to express a forward direction or movement.

But, according to Merriam Webstet, it's also used figuratively.  For example:
Is there anything we can do to hurry this process along? = Is there anything we can do to make this process go faster?

I think you can also use the phrasal verb "speed up" instead of using speed...along as follows:

Drink a lot of water to speed up the process/to speed the process up.

According to Ngram Viewers, the phrase "speed up the process" is far more common and idiomatic than the phrase "speed the process along".